# Angular express add json into mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a json and I want to add directly into my local mongoDB.

model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ObjectsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
o_id: String,
details: Object
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Objects', ObjectsSchema);
```

server code :

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();                        // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                 // mongoose for mongodb
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(database.localUrl);    
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));        // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Session");
next();
});
// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

routes.js

```
var object = require('./model/Objects.model.js');
module.exports = function(app) {

app.post('/api/objects', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    object.create({
        o_id: req.body.id,
        details: req.body.attributes
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });

});};
```

Req.body :

```
[
{
  "id": "lLLLL",
  "attributes": {
    "Name": "Presentation Template, A.1",
    "Type": "Document"
  }
},
{
  "id": "2LLLL",
  "attributes": {
    "Name": "Presentation Template, A.2",
    "Type": "Document"
  }
},..............
]
```

in mongoDB when I do db.objects.find() an element is added but I don't find what I have really added to DB.

The element looks like this : `{ "_id" : ObjectId("574da9ac7dee7e001da0ba25"), "__v" : 0 }`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following change in routes.js

```
details: req.body
```

So the file looks like

```
var object = require('./model/model.js');
module.exports = function(app) {

app.post('/api/objects', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);

    object.create({
        o_id: req.body.id,
        details: req.body
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });

});};
```

And I passed in the following body using advanced rest client

```
[
{
  "id": "lLLLL",
  "attributes": {
    "Name": "Presentation Template, A.1",
    "Type": "Document"
  }
},
{
  "id": "2LLLL",
  "attributes": {
    "Name": "Presentation Template, A.2",
    "Type": "Document"
  }
}
]
```

This is what gets In to the collection :

```
   db.objects.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("574ec4396fd6101c92dfbf0a"),
        "details" : [
                {
                        "attributes" : {
                                "Type" : "Document",
                                "Name" : "Presentation Template, A.1"
                        },
                        "id" : "lLLLL"
                },
                {
                        "attributes" : {
                                "Type" : "Document",
                                "Name" : "Presentation Template, A.2"
                        },
                        "id" : "2LLLL"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

So Basically, there is no body.attribute, you will need to parse the body json array and get the attribute of the object / objects as per your particular requirement . hope this helps

Comment: Thanks u ! That's what i figured out!